# CSS divs with margin auto, not centered in scrolled div when resizes elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem centering divs in another div with overflow:auto; in the beginning all divs are centered with margin: 0 auto; but when i use jquery for resize the last div then an scrollbar appears (as are expected) but the other divs maintain their positions, i want that automatically all the divs get organized on center of the scrolled div.

i resize the las div with:

```
$('#boton').click(function(){
    $('.div2').css({width:'400px'});
});
```

i show it in this fiddle, press the button resize:

http://jsfiddle.net/odabart/cAyVF/1/

**EDIT:**

i don't know which divs will be resized, so i want to accomplish this using only css for automation, jquery is only for example

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want to center the blue div or the yellow divs to the blue div?

Comment: i want that all divs blue or yellow get center in the scroll div when one or more increases their width, like a layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow divs are being centered to the width of the parent element (200px). In order to center all the divs you would have to add another div and resize that div as well with jQuery.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahuvY/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div style='overflow:auto;width:200px;height:300px'>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='boton' value="resize"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#boton').click(function(){
    $('.div2').css({width:'400px'}).parent().css({width:'400px'});
});
```

Comment: this works but i don't know which div will be resized in the practice, i want that this can be done using only css for automatic layout

Comment: You can then setup jQuery to resize the parent of the element being resized.

Comment: @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci I've updated the answer to reflect the latest change.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a wrapper div over all div1s and div2s and change the size of this wrapper div as well. The html code would look like this:

```
<div style='overflow:auto;width:200px;height:300px'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='boton' value="resize"/>
```

And the javascript part would contain one new line:

```
$('#boton').click(function(){
    $('.div2, .wrapper').css({width:'400px'});
});
```

Best regards.

Comment: +1. I also suggest using this unified selector on your command instead of separated two: 
`$('.div2, .wrapper').css({width:'400px'});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the yellow divs to the blue div automatically, I suggest having your jQuery trigger the width of the containing div, and having the blue div expand to match.

**UPDATED PER REQUIREMENTS**

[UPDATED JSFiddle sketch](http://jsfiddle.net/zaYYN/3/)

**jQuery**

```
$('#boton').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').css({width:'400px'});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='boton' value="resize"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.frame {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}

.wrapper { width: 200px; }

.div1{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:block;
}

.div2{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to his requirements

Comment: @Itay Be more specific.

Comment: Sure. He wrote "when i use jquery for resize the last div then an scrollbar appears **(as are expected)**". It's clear that he wants the outer div to remain the same size